# How to pass calculated MSBuild property to projects being built?

Tags: msbuild

I am trying to pass a calculated property value from the TFS proj file into the csproj files of the solution being built but its always the unmodified value that gets passed. I suspect its a task ordering issue but am not sure. Exactly when does the sln read the property value?

the cut down version of my proj file is:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ProductMajorVersion>4</ProductMajorVersion>
  <ProductMinorVersion>5</ProductMinorVersion>
  <ProductBuildNumber>0</ProductBuildNumber>
  <ProductUpdateVersion>0</ProductUpdateVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="BeforeEndToEndIteration">

   <!-- Calculate changeset number -->
   <MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Tfs.TfsClient ToolPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE"
                                 Command="history /s:$(TFSPath) /stopafter:1 /format:detailed /version:T $/mobile/main"
                                 Recursive="true">
   <Output TaskParameter="Changeset" PropertyName="ProductBuildNumber"/>
   </MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Tfs.TfsClient>

   <Message Text="TFS ChangeSetNumber: $(ProductBuildNumber)" />

</Target>

<ItemGroup>
  <SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/../../Main/BuildAll.sln">
    <Targets></Targets>
    <Properties>ProductMajorVersion=$(ProductMajorVersion);ProductMinorVersion=$(ProductMinorVersion);ProductBuildNumber=$(ProductBuildNumber);ProductUpdateVersion=$(ProductUpdateVersion)</Properties>
  </SolutionToBuild>
</ItemGroup>
```

The message correctly outputs the modified ProductBuildNumber but my sln file still reads it as 0.

can anybody help?

Comment: The order in the file does not represent the order in which things are executed. Always confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out!

passing properties inside solutiontobuild is only for static properties. dynamic properties must not be passed that way but instead declared within the target that they are modified as follows:

```
<Target Name="BeforeEndToEndIteration">

  <!-- modifying code -->

  <PropertyGroup>
    <CustomPropertiesForBuild>$(CustomPropertiesForBuild);ProductBuildNumber=$(ProductBuildNumber)</CustomPropertiesForBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```